# Toolchain for fast Webapp

Tags: web-apps, hardware

My goal is to develop a small, locally run web application that is used to control hardware over the MQTT protocol.

Having a job in electronics development, programming itself is familiar to me, but only in the languages C/C#/C++ and Java and solely in projects that have simple or no GUI.So everything that has to too with styling and responsive design is new to me.

The application itself will consist of a menu that lets you switch pages. The pages are all very similar. They all contain a "slider" where the user can move the position.  Every page switch, and slider change, should trigger a function. Most functions will contain stuff like value mapping, and then sending the value to the server. Also, it would be great if the app can be used as a docker image. The app would be viewed via a tablet of smartphone.

To be honest, I would prefer some kind of tool that lets me design the slides by drag-and-drop and would create some prototype functions where I can add my code. I've seen this before but for displays of micro-controllers (TouchGFX).

Is there any recommendation to get this project working in an efficient way?